# LOOPING while scrapping from HTML

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

this is the code so far:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import urllib.request as urllib2

# Initialize parser
parser = etree.HTMLParser()

# First page
url = "https://admn5015-340805.uc.r.appspot.com/2019-01-01.html"

webpage = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=10)
html = webpage.read().decode(encoding="utf-8")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

price = soup.find("td", {"id": "price"}).text
print(price)

likes = soup.find("td", {"id": "likes"}).text
print(likes)

dislikes = soup.find("td", {"id": "dislikes"}).text
print(dislikes)

followers = soup.find("td", {"id": "followers"}).text
print(followers)
```

This codes parse data from this particular webpage, now I have the 3 years of webpage with different dates which needs to extract the same data. how can I loop it and how can I store the data while parsing in a dataframe. The wep page name is the same just the date changes

Comment: for looping you have to use `for`-loop or `while`-loop. But this is basic knowledge which you should already know and you should use it without asking for this.

Comment: It can be simpler if you put code in function (which get parametes - i.e. url) and use this function in `for`-loop like `for url in list_of_urls: your_function(url)`

Comment: maybe first keep result on list (list of rows like `row = [price, likes, dislikes, followers]`) and later convert it to `dataframe` - `df = pd.DataFrame(list_or_rows)`

Comment: if every url is a date then you could use `datetime.datetime()` + `datetime.timedelta(days=1)` to generate all dates and use then with `for`-loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing any amount of python web spider - do yourself a favor and just learn how to use https://scrapy.org/

It supports everything you want, XSLT, cssselect. You build a pipeline that you easily write spiders that will ingest pages storing results as objects that you can write custom handlers for.

You *can* write scrapers that are task specific like you are, but once you learn scrapy you'll be hooked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop then you need `for`-loop or `while`-loop

---

First you could put code in function which gets `url` as parameter

```
def parse(url):
    print('url:', url)
    
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=100)  # on my computer it needs longer `timeout`
    html = response.read().decode(encoding="utf-8")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    date = soup.find("td", {"id": "date"}).text
    print(date)

    price = soup.find("td", {"id": "price"}).text
    print(price)

    likes = soup.find("td", {"id": "likes"}).text
    print(likes)

    dislikes = soup.find("td", {"id": "dislikes"}).text
    print(dislikes)

    followers = soup.find("td", {"id": "followers"}).text
    print(followers)

    print('---')
    
    row = [url, date, price, likes, dislikes, followers]
    
    return row
```

And later you can use this function with list of url and `for`-loop

```
# - before loop -

all_urls = [
    "https://admn5015-340805.uc.r.appspot.com/2019-01-01.html",
    "https://admn5015-340805.uc.r.appspot.com/2019-01-02.html",
    "https://admn5015-340805.uc.r.appspot.com/2019-01-03.html",
]

all_rows = []

# - loop -

for url in all_urls:
    row = parse(url)
    all_rows.append(row)
```

And later you can convert all to dataframe

```
# - after loop -   

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['url', 'date', 'price', 'likes', 'dislikes', 'followers'])

print(df)
```

---

Full code with other changes:

Main problem is that this page has `<meta charcode="utf8">` but file uses chars `latin1` and it needs `encoding="latin1"`

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---   # PEP8: all functions before main code

def parse(url):
    print('url:', url)
    
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=100)  # page needs longer `timeout`
    html = response.read().decode(encoding="latin1")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    date = soup.find("td", {"id": "date"})
    date = date.text if date else ""
    print('date:', date)

    price = soup.find("td", {"id": "price"})
    price = price.text if price else ""
    print('price:', price)

    likes = soup.find("td", {"id": "likes"})
    likes = likes.text if likes else ""
    print('likes:', likes)

    dislikes = soup.find("td", {"id": "dislikes"})
    dislikes = dislikes.text if dislikes else ""
    print('dislikes:', dislikes)

    followers = soup.find("td", {"id": "followers"})
    followers = followers.text if followers else ""
    print('followers:', followers)

    print('---')
    
    row = [url, date, price, likes, dislikes, followers]
    
    return row

# --- main ---

# - before loop -

all_urls = [
    "https://admn5015-340805.uc.r.appspot.com/2019-01-01.html",
    "https://admn5015-340805.uc.r.appspot.com/2019-01-02.html",
    "https://admn5015-340805.uc.r.appspot.com/2019-01-03.html",
]

all_rows = []

# - loop -

for url in all_urls:
    row = parse(url)
    all_rows.append(row)
   
# - after loop -   

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['url', 'date', 'price', 'likes', 'dislikes', 'followers'])

print(df)

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

If all your urls has dates then you could use `datetime.date` to create `start date` (and `end data`) and `datetime.timedelta(days=1)` to create `step`. And you can use `while`-loop

```
# - before loop -

all_rows = []

start = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date.today()
step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

# - loop -

while start <= end:
    url = start.strftime("https://admn5015-340805.uc.r.appspot.com/%Y-%m-%d.html")
    row = parse(url)
    all_rows.append(row)
    start += step
```

---

It could be good to add `try/except` to catch some problems  - but I skip this part.